# "Planet of hats" species progressing out of their hats naturally

Tags: society, culture

I thought of a sentient species, named the Koba, with multiple different races, that was originally created by a creative elder dragon as a spiteful gift to the other elder dragons with each dragon being given a different race of Koba with different traits ingrained into each them to match the personalities of the dragons they we given to.

Now in the present all but one of the dragons have stopped caring for the Koba and the Koba have developed their own cultures. Do you think the traits they were ingrained with still be prevalent, more subdued, or completely gone and what would their cultures look like now that they no longer have a dragon to reinforce their traits?

| The Koba and the dragon they were given to | The trait they were given | Why/where/when they were left |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Purple Koba were given to Fuax the Fearful | They were given a paranoia of everything and a fear of gore | Fuax went insane and left the Purple Koba in their floating fortress around 3,000 years ago |
| The Red Koba were given to Regmus the Ravager | They were made simplish brutes with a battle lust and remember grudges well | They were left in a ginormous subterranean forest after they repeatedly failed to take a city of orcs around 2,000 years ago |
| The Yellow Koba were given to Sena the Vainglorious | They were given beauty, vanity and an attraction to making the beautiful lead | They were left in the desert of glass after they insulted Sena's beauty around 2,000 years ago |
| The Brown Koba were given to Faifn the Greedy | They have a natural greed and appraisal skill | Faifn threw the Koba out on to an island in the poison sea out of fear for its hoard around 2,500 years ago |
| The Orange Koba were given to Crasurs the Valorous | They covet honor and strength | They were left in the golden prairie after Crasurs went off to fight Regmus around 500 years ago |

They were all told of each others existence and are all on or around the same continent.

Comment: can you add more detail? What is the time frame you are looking at? How well do the different races interact with each other? Do they co-exist, do they maintain a rigid caste system? There are plenty of variables that could determine the evolution of a society that should be addressed before it can be answered.

Comment: Isn't this just a "_how should my story go?_"  type question? You're writing the story, and as such you get to decide how your created race evolves its own cultures. Do you want their old traits to remain in the foreground, or would you rather they fade away? These aren't really decisions we can make for you.

Comment: There are other Koba I have designed such as the crimson Koba who's natural sadism and masochism  led them to make games to beat people after a realization that others don't like pain as they do and the white Koba who went from humble farmers of ambrosia to an imperialistic high tech looking city state that worships an eldritch god of their own making. The Koba in the question are the less important ones to the story.

Comment: In the question text, which type of Koba is "they" ? Tip: focus on two dragons. One gives the present, the other receives it. When there is only ONE type of Koba to discuss, the question would be better and more focused. Which Koba would be most disobedient to the dragon ?

Answer (score 2):

**Purple-** Being specifically designed to be paranoid, basically, it wont matter where you put them, they would strive to self isolate themselves. They would do everything they can to hid and keep outsiders out. Their society probably would degrade for the fact they would probably also distrust each other. After 3000 years, their population would drop to a handful that may still continue to breed, but would mostly be akin to LOTR Gollum.

**Red-** Over the course of 2000 years, being isolated beneath the earth in deep dark caves, they would lose their battle lust. After a few hundred years of battling themselves, their population would not be sustainable to keep fighting. They would then change focus on burrowing and mining. Eventually becoming akin to dwarves.

**Yellow-** Being fascinated by beauty and obsessed with their own, after the initial suffering they underwent upon their banishment, they would then make the best of their situation. They are driven to mold the world around themselves to reflect their own beauty. They use the glass of the desert around them to build a fantastic city. They will not respect outsiders, being less than themselves, possibly becoming xenophobic.
Over 2000 years of strutting and posing, natural selection made only the most beautiful to reproduce. The less desirable ones served in the under city or were eventually encouraged to leave the city.
The yellow tend to be arrogant and intolerant of others.

**Brown-** Greed is in need of being satisfied. After centuries of exploitation of everything on their little island, their desire for more drive the necessity to brave the poison sea to seek more riches. Eventually, they many escape the island and begin scouring the world for the riches they desire. Greed is a very polarizing emotion that tends to detract others. out in the world at large, they would be repelled by others of their own kind as they would compete with each other to exploit the local area. They would spread far and wide, hiring members of other races to do their dirty work.
Once every (some periotic period) they would gather in their protected island city to hold festivals exhibiting their accumulated wealth, thus attracting mates to create the next generation. Being the oldest, semi-social race, they probably hold substantial power over the rest of the world.
The brown tend to be boastful, flashy characters but are always seeming and planning on the next big gig. They will enjoy the company of other races, but untrusting of members of their own.

**Orange-** These are the youngest and probably the less obsessives. Their values of honor creates a strong bond to family, community and nation. 500 years in not really a long time to form a real niche, but they are beginning gain a grasp of their surroundings. They are strong and hearty bunch that, for the past 500 years have worked the land. They have gone forth and multiplied. Probably faster than any other race. They built a decent sized kingdom based on agrarian principles. In general, they tend to be peaceful, but when provoked, they can be formidable, due to years toiling in the fields.

To keep to certain tropes, I would suggest realigning colors as certain colors do portray certain ideas, such as green would most likely associate with envy and greed.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's Look at One Real World Example of Traits Being Bred In/Out of a Species...

[image]

Folks estimate that the dog was domesticated [12,500 years ago](http://pettrainonline.org/history-of-the-domestication-of-the-dog). And undomesticated dogs continue to work with primates. It is believed that the [same set of genes](https://www.insidescience.org/news/rare-human-syndrome-may-explain-why-dogs-are-so-friendly) causes soft features and gentle behavior in domesticated dogs. What likely started as an injury in a small population of dogs was mixed in and selected for by breeders, until it was widespread.

### How Does This Inform a Wild Species Breeding Out a Trait?

In the case of domesticated dogs, some genetic information was lost. The only way to "breed back in" wildness would be for wild dogs to introduce the missing genetic information, and for preferences to make this trait more common.

### But You Don't Need to Breed a Trait Out

Can domesticated dogs be trained to become aggressive? Of course : dogs are trained to protect property or people all the time. If there's some kind of pressure creating the need for the trait to be suppressed by training.